# How to define class method second param's type to be based on first param's type?

Tags: typescript, generics, parameters

I want to define the parameter type of my class method's second parameter to be the keys of the method's first parameter.
I have tried something like the following, but obviously that failed miserably ...

```
class MyClass {
    render(param1: ???, param2: keyof Parameters<this['render']>[0] ) {
      ...
    }
}
```

```
const myInstance = new MyClass();
// possible values for render's second param are 'a' | 'b'
myInstance.render({ a: 123, b: 456 }, 'a')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a generic type param on the method and define that as the type of `param1`, then define `param2` to be `keyof T`:

```js
    render<T>(param1: T, param2: keyof T) {
      ...
    }
```

Here's a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAECyBPAwpGsDexY9gJwFMA7AEwLwB4AVAPgAoAHCPCAWwEYAuWKgGliYtWAJm4BrAogD2AMx6wAlJmy4cKnAF9gW0FKJQALrACW+owF5YRAgHcEKNFDoKA3MGCnDAOkKlydDFgIbnZhAGZ+ACNuABYAVgA2WA1+AHIIVNcPMx9iMjwAoJDwqNjE5LTIzLdPA1y-AsDg2FCI2GjYeKSU2FSAL2qgA) Example